# Common Table Expressions (CTE) Inside Teradata Macro?

Tags: sql, teradata, common-table-expression

I want to insert data into a table using a common table expression.
If I just write my statement like this and execute it inside the teradata sql assistant it works:

```
INSERT INTO DB.Table(
...,
...,
)
WITH cte AS (
Select 
a,
b,
....,
from
.....
)
SELECT a, b from cte
UNION 
SELECT ... from cte
```

I've created a macro with the same sql code. When I try to execute the macro, I get the error message: "EXECUTE Failed. 3706: All expressions in a derived table must have an explicit name". Are there any restrictions on using common table expressions inside a teradata macro?

Comment: What does *doesn't work* mean, is there an error message? What's your Teradata release?

Comment: I get the error message: "EXECUTE Failed. 3706: All expressions in a derived table must have an explicit name". But I used an AS + alias for every column in the cte, therefore I don't really understand this message... Teradata release is 15.10.